# buggy behaviour in Scapy

Tags: python, ip, icmp, scapy

I use Scapy's function `send` to send data packets that will generate ICMP packets at routers and dump those ICMP packets with `tcpdump`, launched as a child process.

Then, I will read those ICMP packets back into my program with scapy's built-in `rdpcap` function.

Well, it turns out that `rdpcap` sometimes messes up something and as soon as I want to peek into my captured packets, it returns the following:

```
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> icmpPackets
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/plist.py", line 57, in __repr__
    if self._elt2pkt(r).haslayer(p):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'haslayer'
```

Then, I will just need to call `rdpcap` again on the *same* argument and everything will go back to normal:

```
>>> icmpPackets = rdpcap(tcpdumpFileName)
>>> icmpPackets
<icmpPackets.cap: TCP:0 UDP:0 ICMP:1428 Other:1>
```

This is some bug, right?

EDIT: Ok, the one thing I do before I get that error is the following, which might not be too orthodox, but I don't need the ethernet layer when I'm forging packets. If I remove these two lines, I won't get any such errors:

```
for i in range(len(icmpPackets)):
        icmpPackets[i] = icmpPackets[i].getlayer(IP)
```

I did this before elsewhere and never got a problem. What's happening here?

Comment: You probably updated your version of Scapy unknowingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi,

I don't really understand why you sniff traffic with tcpdump rather than scapy, but anyway... Your problem is not a bug in Scapy but rather in your code. You're replacing each packet with its `.getlayer(IP)` which returns `None` if the packet has no `IP` layer (e.g., `ARP` packets). Hence the exception you get latter.

I think you should replace

```
icmpPackets = rdpcap(tcpdumpFileName)
for i in range(len(icmpPackets)):
    icmpPackets[i] = icmpPackets[i].getlayer(IP)
```

with

```
icmpPackets = PacketList([p[IP] for p in PcapReader(tcpdumpFileName) if IP in p])
```

First of all I think it's more "Pythonic", plus it fixes the problem by removing the packets without `IP` layer. Or you could also use, if you want to have all the packets without the `Ether` layer:

```
icmpPackets = PacketList([p.payload for p in PcapReader(tcpdumpFileName)])
```

Plus you could filter with a BPF filter in tcpdump (`icmp` if you just want `ICMP` packets).